# Lower and upper sums of a bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Assume $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded.

Let $P=\{x_0,...,x_N\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$.

Why, for $1\leq n \leq N$ do we have that

$$\inf\{-f(x),\,\,\,x\in[x_{n-1,x_n}]\}=-\sup\{f(x),\,\,\,x\in[x_{n-1},x_n]\}$$

and

$$\sup\{-f(x),\,\,\,x\in[x_{n-1,x_n}]\}=-\inf\{f(x),\,\,\,x\in[x_{n-1},x_n]\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's isolate all the distractions and pose a simple question that addresses the issue you are asking about.

Construct the set
$$
A = \{ -3, 2, 7\}.
$$
And define the set
$$
A_{neg} = \{-x \; : x \in A\} = \{3, -2, -7\}.
$$
Now compute each of:
$$
\min A, \quad \max A, \quad \min A_{neg}, \quad \max A_{neg}.
$$
Examine these four quantities.  Are there pairs that are negatives of each other? Which ones?  Write them down.

If this isn't yet giving satisfactory insight, try some **slightly** more complicated choices $A$: e.g., $A = \{ -7, -1, 0 \} \cup \mbox{(the set of all positive integers)}$.  This one has no $\max$, so need to use $\sup$ instead.

In your question, the $A$ is more complicated: it is the range of $f$ on $[x_{n-1}, x_{n}]$, and you have to use $\inf, \sup$ instead of $\min, \max$.  But, the principle is the same as in the first example I gave.

Answer (score 1):

These are just special cases of the following general result, which you should prove on your own:

> For a subset $A$ of the real numbers, $$\inf(-A) = - \sup A$$.

Here, $-A := \{-x : x \in A\}$.